# Polymer.Dart linter gives warnings about ng-view tags used by Angular.Dart

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, angular-dart

I'm getting a Polymer warning every time I save HTML files with Angular.Dart routing logic:

```
[Warning from polymer (Linter) on datacea|web/datacea.html]:
line 41, column 10 of web\datacea.html: custom element with name "ng-view" not found. See      http://goo.gl/5HPeuP#polymer_11 for details.
<ng-view>
^^^^^^^^^
```

I've already tried adding datacea.html (this the file in question) as an entry_points item under transformers in my pubspec.yaml file. This seems to have no effect on this particular issue.

```yaml
transformers:
 - angular
 - polymer:
    entry_points:
      -web/datacea.html
```

This doesn't affect the execution of the program, but is very annoying. Is there way to get Polymer to understand that ng-view is not a custom polymer element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there aren't many good options to handle this. I didn't know Polymer checks this because it is perfectly valid to have a custom tag without it being a Polymer element (as in your example).

you can

- ignore the warning
- disable Polymer linter

```yaml
  - polymer:
      lint: false
```

see also http://dartbug.com/21237#c5

- create a bug report at http://dartbug.com

Comment: I guess that will have to do as the answer. I am a bit baffled that the Angular and Polymer teams haven't dealt with this issue. I can't be the only one trying to use Polymer components within an Angular framework.

Comment: The problem is that many argue that the polymer linter **should** warn when no custom element definition was found for a tag containing a dash, but it is perfectly valid to have such a tag without a custom element definition. Angular.dart and Polymer.dart used together isn't a beaten path yet.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Is there a way to suppress the warning for the custom tag instead of turning off the linter?

Comment: @jakebird451 not for now AFAIK, but there is a new strategy work in progress, but I assume it will still take quite some time until this lands for this scenario. The Angular 2 team is building a plugin for the analyzer. The analyzer allows to disable single lint rules using the `.analysis_options` file (dev release only currently). I hope something similar will be built for Polymer 1.x. They are discussing to support suppressing single lint hints/warnings in the source using source comments in the analyzer, but again AFAIK no actual work  was started yet.